# Why do we get compile time errors for redundant accessibility modifiers?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction

Compile time Error

> the accessibility modifier of the set accessor must be more
>   restrictive than the property or indexer

during a scenerio like

> private string TestString { get; private set; }

Why does this cause a compilation error?  I understand **more restrictive**.  Still, this shouldn't cause any real problems.  It's an unecessary modification rather than a build killing issue. Why kill the build rather than toss up a warning?

Comment: It is confusing. If it ever becomes a vote, I'm in favor of this error.

Comment: It's no more confusing that unused variables which are optimized out at compile time.  Why can't we do the same thing? It strikes me as inconsistent with the norm having a compile time error that really is a readability problem.

Comment: Presumably your *real* question is "Why is the language designed such that the only access modifiers that can be specified are strictly more restrictive"? The compiler is just following the specification.

Comment: Make it "confidential" or "top secret". It will work then.

Comment: @JonSkeet answered my question in a comment.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: Do you want me to change that to an answer then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anything, the error message might be better read as "Redundant code found" or something to the like since:

`private string TestString { get; private set; }`

is really the same as:

`private string TestString { get; set; }`

But, because the compiler enforces the rule, it does make sense that you get it since `private`, of course, can not be *more* restricted than itself.